# Pandas time series analysis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to SQL/Pandas thus the question.
I have 3 tables,

```
['invites','quotes', 'users']
```

The structure of each of them are

```
invites->invite_id, request_id, user_id, date

quotes ->quote_id, invite_id, data

....
```

I've run the following query to join quotes against invites.

```
'SELECT i.invite_id, q.quote_id, i.sent_time FROM invites AS i INNER JOIN quotes AS q ON i.invite_id = q.invite_id'
```

This gives me the following table,

```
invite_id, quote_id, date
```

This I've imported into a Data Frame.
Now I want to find two things from this data Frame.

```
quotes_per_invite

quotes_per_invite_on_a_per_day_basis
```

I've no idea how to do this. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Read about `groupby` function.

Answer (score 1):

Check pandas documentation on [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

To count all quotes per invite

```
df.groupby('invite_id')['quote_id'].count()
```

or to count distinct or unique quotes per invite

```
df.groupby('invite_id')['quote_id'].nunique()
```

`*HINT*` You can use a list in the groupby.

Comment: @MelissaStewart did that help you?